# Am I using “gush” and “blast” correctly?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know whether I’m using *gush* and *blast* correctly in the following sentence:

> I felt as if I had accidentally opened a fire hydrant and let a **gush** of
>   water **blasting** out uncontrollably.

Whereas in Spanish, my mother tongue, there’s only one word to describe a powerful flow of water (*chorro*), in English there are many:

> jet, squirt, spirt, stream, blast, gush, effluent

So, I’m a bit confused.

Comment: I don't like it much. Better would be *"let a **blast** of water **gush** out uncontrollably"*, but I'd probably prefer *a torrent of water* anyway.

Comment: *Surge* would also do well as the verb in that sentence. And I think I prefer *rush* to *gush*, for what it's worth.

Comment: Referring to the flow from a fire hydrant as uncontrollable is incorrect and should not be done if you intend to write something believable.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the suggestion. I guess the sentence is better off without that adverb.

Comment: @jwpat7: That is a trifling objection. If you don't have a fireman's wrench, it is uncontrollable by you. Everything is relative.

Comment: @Robusto, relative to “I ... opened a fire hydrant”, the notion that “I don't have a wrench” is absurd. ... You might be right that the error of calling it uncontrollable is a trifle, but it is the sort of error that breaks the reader's belief that an author is describing events that could be real.

Comment: @jwpat7: The speaker is describing an imaginary situation where someone has "accidentally" opened the hydrant. No wrench is mentioned or even implied.

Comment: I’m actually not sure that *chorro* has no synonyms in Spanish. Certainly there are related words like *corriente, torrente, géiser, cascada, salto*.  There are also figurative words like *ducha, reguero, regato,* or even *diluvio*, along with derived terms like *chorretada, chorrada, chorreo, chorreón*. But probably the [Spanish Language & Usage StackExchange site](http://spanish.stackexchange.com) would be better for this.

Comment: @tchrist: do you mean to say that 'thesaurus' is not an English word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *gush* and *blast* work fine as nouns or verbs.  Your sentence is perfectly fine as it stands.

Personally, I wouldn’t use *blast* in either position here.  I feel as though *blast* may be better suited for air or sound than for liquid.

Comment: _Blast_ works for liquids, too, but it has more to do with the Force (F=ma) of the exit, and its results in the form of damage. Since the most common form of blast is a chemical explosive, that takes care of air and sound; it's less frequent with liquids but it's OK. _Gush_ implies strong output pressure and steady output, but it's not explosive and need make no noise. It's also pretty narrowly restricted to liquids, except possibly in submarine or space-travel contexts, where gases are always contained.

Comment: Eloquently put.

Comment: The meaning of _blast_ is coherent with the [phonosemantics of _BL-_ words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/bl.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler, a minor point: perhaps *bleat* should have checkmark 3 like *blab* or perhaps 1 & 3 like *blat*.

Comment: Quite possibly. Those are my judgements and I usually err in a conservative direction -- if in doubt, don't. I was interested in clear cases only, to set a bottom limit on how complex the phenomenon has to be. It turned out to be a very high bottom limit. Plus, there's a considerable amount of individual variation in something so non-lexical.

Comment: @John It seems like you might be able to provide a lovely and thoughtful answer to this question. *smiles, bats eyelids*