# What is the difference between the words “stream”, “flow” etc.?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms

What is the difference in meaning and usage between the nouns “stream”, “flow” (“pour” is excluded from this list based on comments) and probably other words with similar meaning? What is more appropriate when talking about news or other entities of content continuously appearing on a website, other discrete object constantly appearing on one side, moving to other and disappearing there?

Comment: *Pour* isn't a noun. Also, it's helpful to us if you first look up each word in a dictionary and try to solve the problem you have before you ask us, and tell us what you've found, so that we can see what you already know.

Comment: @MattЭллен According to Webster and other dictionaries I used “pour” can be used as noun and is a synonym of “stream”: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pour

Comment: Nope. *Pour* is a synonym for the verb *stream*, not the noun.

Comment: @MattЭллен I admit it's so. But dictionaries clearly state “stream” as synonym to “pour” in section marked “noun”. Is it a mistake in Webster (see link above to verify this) and other dictionaries? What is a more authoritative dictionary to verify such things?

Comment: @MattЭллен Several dictionaries list pour as a noun in US English (as Denis indicated above) and it is often used as a noun to refer to an amount of wine poured in a tasting (although the OP is asking about news feeds).

Comment: @bib then I defer to your greater knowledge of AmE. I can't put *pour* in a sentence as a noun, but I'm a BrE speaker.

Comment: @MattЭллен Based on your comments I see that “pour” at lest is not widely used in this context, so I've excluded it from the list.

Comment: @MattЭллен "The tasting room was known for its very generous *pours*." (I live in a wine region.) I have also heard the use of *pour* as a synonym for *downpour*, but not very frequently.

Comment: @bib that is a very technical usage. 'a pour of water' is ungrammitical in AmE.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110884/am-i-using-gush-and-blast-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I hear or read the word, **stream**, first of all I think of a *fast flowing*, rather narrow, *fresh water* river. So these word associations fit rather nicely when we talk about something that is constantly moving, and always renewing itself (*fresh*).

If I am sick in hospital I can say: **I had a constant stream of visitors.**

An online newspaper website will provide: **a stream of news articles.**

A 24 hours news programme will boast: **Live stream coverage from ABC News**

**Flow** on the other hand, *usually* describes how liquid runs continuously in one direction, its meaning is quite similar to (a) stream but it lacks the idea of being constantly updated; fresh and new. It is however, in my opinion, more versatile.

Flow is *normally* collocated with *hair*, *liquids*, *rivers*, *alcohol*, *words* (written and spoken), *ideas*, *traffic* and *information*:

- Her long black hair flowed past her shoulders
- Champagne flowed freely all evening.
- "... he spoke in a rich bass voice, with an easy flow of language.."
- Ideas flowed from her pen
- Traffic is flowing freely on the motorway tonight
- A constant flow of information.

There are many other collocations with flow which you will find in any good dictionary. Some you may be able to substitute with the noun or adjective "stream" for example, *information*, others much less so.

Comment: *Stream* is about continuity (look back at your example, 'constant stream'), not about speed. "run or flow in a continuous current in a specified direction": *she sat with tears streaming down her face*; figurative: *sunlight streamed through the windows* (http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stream) ***Flow*** incidentally, can be intermittent (sorry about that again!).

Comment: @kris I expressed my personal feelings, "I think of", to help illustrate why that word is used in certain contexts. Nonetheless I do believe you are nitpicking, as streams are often more quick flowing compared to larger rivers.

Comment: @Kris "Some you may be able to substitute with the noun or adjective "stream" **for example**, information."

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it is very uncommon to use the word *flow* in the context of:

> "news (or other entities of content) continuously appearing on a
>   website"

*Stream* in this context commonly refers to live video.

The word you are looking for as mentioned in the comments is ***feed*** — this is the commonly used noun for content continuously appearing on a website.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Before you think about the words, get the metaphor fixed in your mind.

- What is flowing? News? Words? Text?
- Is it incompressible like water or compressible like a gas?
- Where is it flowing from?
- Where is it flowing to?
- What is its channel?
- How much pressure does it have and where does it come from?
- Speed, volume, throughput, variability, tides/news cycle

Write up the metaphor frame -- a long description of the metaphor as you see it, but be literal. Use all the fluid verbs you can think of, but use a term for a fluid in the description, instead of *news*.

Then substitute *news* for the fluid and see which ones are cliches, which ones are just too weird, and which ones work. There'll be some of each for every metaphor frame.

For more about frames, see [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu).

Comment: I think you are over-thinking the question - it appears that the OP wants to know which noun represents continuous content appearing on a website - a feed.  Admittedly I am taking the end part of the question as the more pertinent aspect because I believe that is the ultimate goal of the question.

Comment: @Sam: you just provided a common term that involves a completely separate metaphor, one of -eating-. John is basically saying 'it depends' on what you want, and there are lots of possibilities. But then there are possibilities, and then there is what people actually do. AV is usually _streamed_, and news items come in a _feed_. That's just the way  people generally call these things.

Comment: I disagree - the OP makes it clear what he wants - he wants to know the noun to describe continuous web content.  I don't see why this is not clear?

Comment: There are a lot of them, and they vary. According to metaphors. That's all.

Comment: In my native language (Russian) there is a single word for stream, flow, gush and it can be used to describe discrete object constantly appearing on one side, moving to other and disappearing there, including news items on the site. That's why I don't take it as metaphor.

Comment: In English they are metaphors, however. Different languages use different systems.

Comment: Ok, I meant "discrete objects constantly appearing on one side, moving to other and disappearing there". News or blog post is just an example of such objects. What is proper word to describe this movement the best (with or without metaphor)?